# Resizing Image in Python 3 Fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am currently trying to resize a PNG image and PIL fails to do so.

```
    image_path = path + filename
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    img2 = img.resize(('100', '100'))
```

I get the following error in Python3.

```
 img2 = img.resize(('100', '100'))
 AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'resize
```

Comment: Can you try displaying the image you load? I have a feeling that it doesn't load properly.

Comment: I ran img.show() and it displays it.

Comment: Oh, why does your tuple of sizes contain strings? I'm pretty sure PIL expects a tuple of integers, i.e. `(100, 100)`, not `('100', '100')`

Comment: I think this is one of those cases where seeing the *whole* error trace would be helpful.